# How do I stop the screen flashing black when switching between Detail pages in an iOS MasterDetail Xamarin form?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, master-detail

I have the following **MasterDetailPage** which I use to switch between 3 different views as shown below. My landing page is the HomePage.

In **iOS**, when switching between the different pages the screen flashes to black for I'm guessing around 300-400ms before the next page appears. The problem is particularly pronounced when switching back to the HomePage from the 2 other pages.

Is there anyway to prevent this black screen occurring? It looks unprofessional and makes the app look unstable.

(By the way, no such flashing occurs in Android for the same code).

```
    public partial class MDPage : MasterDetailPage
    {
        ...
        ...
        
        public void NavigateTo(PageType pt)
        {
            switch (pt)
            {
                case PageType.Home:
                    {
                        if (_home == null)
                            _home = new HomePage();
                        page = _home;
                    }
                    break;
                case PageType.Edit:
                    {
                        if (_edit == null)
                            _edit = new EditPage();
                        page = _edit;
                    }
                    break;
                case PageType.Settings:
                    {
                        if (_settings == null)
                            _settings = new SettingsPage();
                        page = _settings;
                    }
                    break;

            }
            Detail = page;
        }
        
        ...
        ...
    }
```

Comment: That shouldn't be happening. If you make a new project with the MasterDetail template, and don't make any changes, does it happen on that new project?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Steve. I've noticed it's happening on an iPhone6 test phone I have. It also occurs on an iPhone12 but is not so noticeable because of the speed at which it occurs, so I suspect it is a performance issue for the older phone at the moment, which I'm not so concerned about. I'll try your test though when I have time to come back to it and let you know the results. Cheers

Comment: I haven't used MasterDetail template (I don't use any built-in templates; developed my own years ago). But I'm surprised that happens at all on iPh 12. What iOS version? App should not switch pages until it is ready to draw the new page, complete with UI controls. Worst case, there should be some way to change default color to gray or white, so is less noticeable.